# Can forensic investigators find my webmail emails in my laptop?

Tags: email, forensics

When I send an email using the web interface of Yahoo Mail or Gmail, can the email can be found somewhere (even if encrypted) on my laptop by forensic investigators? Somewhere on my hard drive or RAM? I am concerned only about the possibility to find my email somewhere in my laptop, not elsewhere.

Comment: The e-mail itself is not saved on your laptop, no. Unless, of course, such an investigation had been prepared for beforehand. e.g. keylogging.

Comment: I'm going to refrain from actually answering (more completely) as I myself suspect from the specifics of your question that you might not be using this information for legitimate purposes, but email that you read is cached by the browser unless otherwise specified by the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most browsers are coded/have default configuration to not cache HTTPS pages, so your emails will not be intentionally written to disk. However, other possibilities exist:

- Some webmails may cache email contents in local browser storage, for faster access the next time you use the service.
- Swap/page file: parts of your browser's memory may be saved to disk to free up RAM for other programs. They may not be cleaned up instantly (or at all) when your browser closes.
- Your anti-virus/firewall/etc. may intercept HTTPS traffic to check for viruses. If could record some data for logging/temporary processing/etc.
- Bad plug-ins, online activity trackers, etc.

Most stuff written to disk can be recovered given enough resources.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, they can.
 But so can anyone with physical access to:

- Your account
- Your Laptop
- Your Hard disks
- Your Memory
- Your processor
- You

as to whether this is an issue consider the following. 
 in your question you  state `When I send an email using Yahoo Mail or GMail to a friend.`
this means you all ready SEND your data over the internet to someone else and exposes not only you, but the receiver and the message in transit for interception and inspection by 3rd parties. (The FBI is a 3rd party)

When you Send anything over a network it transitions through several different components and states. In theory, on any of these states and transitions, your message (or its packets) can be intercepted / duplicated.
To illustrate this, to send a email with no subject or body to me@example.com we get a email message that has to go through the full TCP/IP stack on my system, through the modem I use to connect to my ISP, through the ISP's Network , to the destination network of my recipient, through the TCP/IP stack of the receiving mail server and finally (through the same TCP/IP stack on the mail server) through the TCP/IP stack of the recipient.

this means there or so many possible locations for a attacker / 3rd party to see that I send this specific message I do not worry about the evidence on my system. (since there is so much evidence they can prove there case without that evidence)

The only methodology that would over some protection against this is using end-to-end encryption with external hardware keys (like a smart-card or similar technology)

Comment: Should be a comment.

Comment: OP states interested in laptop only.

Comment: true, but when you trace back this question you can not escape the 'other' side. You can not 'send' and than disregard that you 'send'. I did focus the answer around the laptop.